# Referencing ffmpeg dependencies for PyAV installation

Tags: apt, ffmpeg

I need to install `PyAV` for loading and using videos as input (as a `Tensor`) to a `pytorch` model. When I try to install the package in my virtual environment I get the following build error:

```
Collecting av
  Using cached av-11.0.0.tar.gz (3.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      Package libavformat was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libavformat.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'libavformat' found
      Package libavcodec was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libavcodec.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'libavcodec' found
      Package libavdevice was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libavdevice.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'libavdevice' found
      Package libavutil was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libavutil.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'libavutil' found
      Package libavfilter was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libavfilter.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'libavfilter' found
      Package libswscale was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libswscale.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'libswscale' found
      Package libswresample was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libswresample.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'libswresample' found
      pkg-config could not find libraries ['avformat', 'avcodec', 'avdevice', 'avutil', 'avfilter', 'swscale', 'swresample']
```

If possible I want to use my existing installation of`ffmpeg` installed through the `apt` package manager. When I call the command `ffmpeg` in terminal I get the following ouput:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

The files that were not found in `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` are exactly the ones I assume are installed with `apt`. My question is where do I find them in the `apt` installation so I can put them in the environment varaible?